# Android - Fragment intent

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

What is the best to do in my situation? I have a Fragment that contains a ListView and a button, when i click a button it should open a window where the user will fill in edittext fields and once he presses okay it dismisses and puts it into database, it will then update the Listview in the fragment and show automatically.

Should I start an intent activity? What is best solution

Comment: You could do a Dialog Fragment if you knew you weren't going to have any other child fragments or an Activity.  Both would work then same then in the on resume in your fragment make it update whatever is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new activity. You create fragments when you need to change a portion of a view. If you create a new view completely different from the one you have, you should consider create a new activity and get your result back on your previous activity with `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: How can I inflate an activity within a fragment?  Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), activity.class);
                startActivity(i);

Comment: You can't inflate an activity inside a fragment. Fragments are activity dependants, not the other way around.

Comment: SO when Im in a fragment and I click the button in my fragment I want to open a window where the user can input his details to be added in database and pass the added info back to the fragment's lsitview

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Context, ActivityIWantToStart.class);
startActivity(i);
```